# How do you Print the cubes of all integers from -10 to 10, including both ends in python

Tags: python

I got my question from this https://snakify.org/en/lessons/while_loop/steps/2/
can't seen to find out the answer for quite some time hope someone will explain to me how to do it

Comment: first make a loop that iterates a variable `i` from -10 to 10. Then elevate each of this numbers to the cube `i**3` and print it.

Comment: `for a in range(-10,10+1):
    print(a**3)` Try this.

Comment: I don't think using a for loop is the expected solution of the while loop tutorial

Comment: Copy the example code you were given. It computes squares (`**2`). Now, can you figure out how to change that to produce cubes instead of squares?

Answer (score 0):

Answer using while loop:

```
i=-10
while i <= 10:
    print(i**3)
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
-1000
-729
-512
-343
-216
-125
-64
-27
-8
-1
0
1
8
27
64
125
216
343
512
729
1000
```